# Python rounding 'issue' when calculating modulo on fractinos

Tags: python, modulo, fractions

So I was playing around just mindlessly in an interactive shell with exponential notation and I got confused. See below the operations and returned values:

`>>> 1e-100*1e99*10%.99`

`0.010000000000000009`

First I thought this is due to large numbers but then I tried this:

`>>> 1%0.9`

`0.09999999999999998`

`>>> 1%0.1`

`0.09999999999999995`

`>>> 2.3%2`

`0.2999999999999998`

Why aren't the answers .01, .09 and .3 respectively?